# Value at risk, risk-neutral vs real-world probability measures

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, value-at-risk, real-world-measure

Does anyone know if there is any link between the Value at Risk of risk-neutral distribution and of the real-world distributions of asset rate of returns?

Comment: VaR under $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ are typically different. In special cases like the BS model there is a simple mapping between the two as the risk neutral density is a shifted version of the actual density.

Comment: I elaborate a bit more on @fesman's comment. You may think about this as follows: The measure $\mathbb{P}$ holds information about the real world. Unfortunately, it is very very hard to pin down and we do a lot of time series analysis to get something meaningful (?) from observed prices. You may think of $\mathbb{P}$ also as a **time series** measure. $\mathbb{Q}$, on the other hand, is implied by derivatives (options). It is very rich, implies no-arbitrage, and is only during a short time period '*constant'*. $\mathbb{Q}$ can be interpreted as a **cross-sectional** measure.

Comment: .. The two measures may be linked under some model (as @fesman postulated), but that's where the problem is: You need some quite stron model assumptions in order to 'leak' information from measure into the other, e.g. to get tail information.

Comment: Value at Risk is a percentile in a distribution of returns. These returns are meant to "predict the future", and so in my opinion would always have to computed under the real world measure. It doesn't make sense to compute VaR under $\mathbb{Q}$. The most basic VaR would be just a historical sample of realized returns: a percentile from these realized returns would be selected, then this percentile return would be applied to the current spot to project the "Value at Risk" return. Even simulated VaR would be typically calibrated to historical returns (i.e. "Real world measure $\mathbb{P}$).

Comment: Ps: I have actually never come across VaR calibrated to the pricing measure $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JanStuller I agree that people are ultimately interested in VaR under the actual measure. But the question is relevant if one is interested in using future looking information from options prices to help construct VaR. I have seen some attempts to do so, but agree historical estimation is the common approach, possibly due to complications highlighted above.

Comment: @fesman: Option vols include risk-premium, and so tend to over-estimate forward-looking volatility (when compared to actual realized vol). Same issue with CDSs: the CDS spreads massively over-estimate the probabilities of default, when compared to actual realized default frequencies. For these reasons, I would personally be against using the $\mathbb{Q}$-implied quantities for any forward-looking estimates of real physical phenomena.

Comment: @JanStuller Definitely you should not naively replace actual expected vol with IV. But the broader issue is that it is difficult to disentangle the risk premium from expected real world volatility.

Comment: @fesman: that is spot-on, separating the risk-premium from implied quantities is a problem that I have never seen solved properly. Do you by any chance have any material or papers published on that? I might actually make it a stand-alone question to get more answers.

Comment: @JanStuller There are some statistical studies of variance risk premiums like this (http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/lwu/papers/CarrWuRFS2009.pdf). Steve Ross did some work on extracting the physical density from option prices (https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2199487), but these results are apparently a bit controversial. These come to mind immediately though there must be other relevant papers.

Comment: @fesman: thanks so much! Those papers look interesting, started reading them and I look forward to going through them properly over the weekend!